# Ruby 3.2.1 Installation Issues on a Mac (Shell Integration is not Enabled)

Tags: ruby, homebrew, asdf

When trying to switch between ruby versions on my Mac, I get a "Shell Integration is not enabled. Please ensure you source asdf in your shell" message and doesnt allow me to switch to the latest version that I've already installed (3.2.1).

How can I enable the shell integration?, how can I ensure that I source asdf in my shell?....

Many thanks

Comment: Make sure you install asdf correctly. https://asdf-vm.com/guide/getting-started.html#_1-install-dependencies Make sure to use your correct shell. Newer macOS versions default to zsh while older versions use bash by default.

Comment: Also, note that on macOS Terminal starts a login shell by default, not just an interactive shell, so you may need to move various things to your login configuration files like ~/.zprofile rather than ~/.zshrc.